# When a server sends a copy of SSL certificate, the connection is encrypted?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

have anyone know if the SSL certificate copy it's send encrypted to the client or decrypted? Do the certificate travel in plaintext at the beginning? Without a trustStore key on the client side is hard to believe that is encrypted. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TLS 1.2 and lower the certificate is send in plain. With TLS 1.3 it is already encrypted.

Comment: Although in modern networks usually if an attacker can see the traffic they can also make their own connection and get the cert effectively in clear -- the paradigm where we only worry about passive listening attacks mostly went out with the end of the Cold War -- plus certs issued by public CAs are now publicly logged to detect misissuance.